# Working with semaphores and shared memory under Linux

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory, semaphore

I need to write a program that is creating a N amount of sub processes and every single one of them adds one to a shared memory variable. My idea is to use semaphores and shared memory, but the processes are not waiting for each other and the shared memory variable is also not working as I want it.

**mydefs.h**

```
#ifndef __MYDEFS__H__
#define __MYDEFS__H__
// Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#endif // __MYDEFS__H__
```

**main.c**

```
#include "mydefs.h"
#define PROC_COUNT 3
#define INITAL_MARKER_VALUE 0
#define PID_LEN 32

char mypid[PID_LEN];

int main()
{
    int i, shm_id;
    sem_t mutex;
    if(sem_init(&mutex,1,1) < 0)
    {
        perror("semaphore initilization");
        exit(0);
    }
    shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 4*sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (shm_id < 0) {
         printf("shmget error\n");
    }
    int *shmpointer = shmat(shm_id,0,0);
    memset(mypid, 0, sizeof(mypid));
    sprintf(mypid, "%06d", getpid());

    for(i = 0; i < PROC_COUNT; i++)
    {
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            while(sem_wait(&mutex)!=0);
            execl("slaveproc", "slaveproc", mypid, (char *)0);
            shmpointer += 1;
            sem_post(&mutex);
            perror("\n Can't exec slave program. Cause ");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    sleep(1);
    printf("%d\n", *shmpointer);
    return 0;
}
```

**slaveproc.c**

```
#include "mydefs.h"

int marker; // Marker value

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    master_pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("\n --------------------------------------");
    printf("\n I'm the slave proc!");
    printf("\n My pid: %d", getpid());
    printf("\n My master's pid: %d", master_pid);
    printf("\n --------------------------------------");
    for(;;) pause();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. How did you come to the conclusion that "processes are not waiting for each other" and what exactly do you mean by "not working as I want"? Please describe exactly the expected output and the actual output. But for starters you have code after the `execl` that which will never get executed unless `execl` fails - `execl` does not return on success. So in the success case `shmpointer` will not be incremented and `sem_post` will not be called.

Comment: Furthermore, having a `sleep` in the parent is no guarantee that all the child processes have completed when the `printf` is run. It may be ok for a quick test but would require proper synchronisation in the parent for production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (or at least "a problem") is that `mutex` is not in shared memory: it's allocated on the stack. When you `fork()`, the new process will have a completely separate copy from the old process, so calling `sem_wait(&mutex)` on one process will not affect the other process's `mutex` at all.

You should put `mutex` in the shared memory:

```
int main()
{
    int i, shm_id;
    shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(sem_t) + 4*sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    if (shm_id < 0) {
         printf("shmget error\n");
    }
    int *shmpointer = shmat(shm_id,0,0);
    sem_t *mutex = shmpointer;
    shmpointer = (void*)shmpointer + sizeof(sem_t);
    if(sem_init(mutex,1,1) < 0)
    {
        perror("semaphore initilization");
        exit(0);
    }        
    memset(mypid, 0, sizeof(mypid));
    sprintf(mypid, "%06d", getpid());

    for(i = 0; i < PROC_COUNT; i++)
    {
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            while(sem_wait(mutex)!=0);
            execl("slaveproc", "slaveproc", mypid, (char *)0);
            shmpointer += 1;
            sem_post(mutex);
            perror("\n Can't exec slave program. Cause ");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    sleep(1);
    printf("%d\n", *shmpointer);
    return 0;
}
```

You're also never writing to the memory in `shmpointer` (perhaps you meant `(*shmpointer) += 1`?), but I'll let you figure that out on your own.

Comment: After some reading and your answer I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: I'd like to point out that `(void*)shmpointer + sizeof(sem_t)` is undefined behavior as per the specification. While it could still be compiled correctly (just because GCC is nice), you cannot know the size of the data pointed by a void pointer at compile time, so you should cast to `char*` or better `uint8_t*` to be sure not to cause undefined behavior. In fact, GCC should warn you about this (at least with `-pedantic`): `warning: pointer of type void* used in arithmetic`.